# Greasepencil render only renders half of the frames

Tags: rendering, animation, grease-pencil

I'm fairly new to blender but I've been making animations with Greasepencil for a while and haven't had this issue yet. I'm rendering a large video as a png sequence (5000+ frames) with eevee. About 2800 frames were rendered perfectly, but the rest of them showed up as completely blank transparent images.
I thought the problem might be the storage on my computer, but after deleting plenty of other animation files and resetting my computer, the same images failed to render. From what I can tell, there's no difference between the frames that rendered and the frames that didn't.
Here's an image of my settings.
[image]

Comment: just a question: if you render png anyway, why don't you render "just" the rest of your failed png? or just one to check whether the reason is your setup or your computer? It's just a waste of time to render everything again if you already have rendered (+saved) pngs

Comment: Hi, I didn't render everything again. I don't know if it was clear, but I have tried rendering just the failed parts and nothing will work, but everything is fine if it's one of the frames that already rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out and am posting the answer in here in case anyone has the same problem.

I think Blender had some kind of limit on how many frames I could render at a time in a project. I'm not sure why, but I was able to render the broken frames by copying the project, deleting the keyframes for what I had already rendered, and then rendering the broken parts.

I put those *PNG* files in a separate folder, then went back to my original Blend project and added the frames to the video editor.